# TYPO3 and Symfony problems (Non-Composer Mode) / CLI cronjob problem

Tags: symfony, typo3, command-line-interface

I have trouble with my TYPO3 10.4(.21) project. When installing Extenions I got this error but after that everything works.

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\SelfCheckingResourceInterface::isFresh(int $timestamp) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\ResourceInterface::isFresh($timestamp) in /.../typo3_src-10.4.21/vendor/symfony/config/Resource/SelfCheckingResourceInterface.php on line 29
```

The only thing that do not work is the CLI task to run.

```
/usr/bin/php7.4-cli -f /.../typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 scheduler:run
```

Here I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Console\Application::setCommandLoader()
thrown in file /.../typo3_src-10.4.21/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Console/CommandApplication.php
in line 67
```

I already build many TYPO3 Projects but have no clue what goes wrong here (have not initially build that project).

Comment: You should provide a full stack trace, without it's only wild guessing for those errors!

Comment: My first thought was the the first error is related to a fault in symfony, but I verified the code in version 5.3.0 which is used in TYPO3 10.4 and can't discover any faults. So I assume you should clear all caches in the install-tool or on cli, perhaps the fault is gone then. If the error persists, check the version of symfony.
I'm not sure if the paths in your project are all correct (related to `/.../`) so perhaps check that too, also that every source-package exists only once (respecting symlinks surely).

Comment: In my opinion PHP has problems resolving the namespaces to the symfony classes. The path is definitely correct. I have cleared all caches in install tool many times as well as recreated the autoload informations but the symfony classes do not get included in autoload map. But I think thats normal since another project has them not included too but the CLI cronjob works.

Comment: Clear cache on CLI do not work, too. Same error. Also tried an older version of 10.4(.10).

Answer (score 0):

Uragh...the inital developer had symfony classes in an extension folder. Found it by searching the location of that Symfony class file.

```
$reflector = new \ReflectionClass("Symfony\Component\Console\Application");
echo $reflector->getFileName();
```

Saw that the file points to an extension folder with symfony files of that project instead of the regular symfony files in the TYPO3 sources vendor folder.

Answer (score -2):

Update: forget it, the patch that introduced that issue has not been merged to 10.4.21 ... Sorry for fuzz.

Guessing, not entirely sure without deeper look, but that might be related to a patch that has been introduced with 10.4.21 and is reverted for upcoming 10.4.22:
https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/commit/088a85fcb1f09a829d622a06a5f9dfaff1b19244